# Display JSON values depending on presence of other key using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I am new to JavaScript, tried below code and not able to get it. I have gone through many other post but didn't work.

Output: Check if AUTO damage is present. If Yes, get count and display First & Last for the same.

```js
var myObj, i, x = "";
myObj = {
  "Initial": {
    "claim": [{
      "first": "abc",
      "last": "xyz",
      "damage": {
        "auto": true,
        "manual": true
      }
    }, {
      "first": "mne",
      "last": "odc",
      "damage": {
        "manual": true
      }
    }, {
      "first": "svc",
      "last": "tre",
      "damage": {
        "auto": true
      }
    }, {
      "first": "tre",
      "last": "hdf",
      "damage": {}
    }]
  }
}

var myObj = myObj.Initial.claim;

console.log(myObj);

for (i = 0; i < myObj.length; i++) {
  x += myObj.first[i] + "<br>";
  x += myObj.damage.auto[i] + "<br>";
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "get count" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First `myObj.Initial.claim` is an array not an object, it's better to name it `myArr` instead of `myObj`.

Before accessing an object property which can be present or not, you have to check for it before doing that using `myObj.hasOwnProperty` method.

```js
var myObj, i, x = "";
myObj = {
  "Initial": {
    "claim": [
      {
        "first": "abc",
        "last": "xyz",
        "damage": {
          "auto": true,
          "manual": true
        }
      }, 

      {
        "first": "mne",
        "last": "odc",
        "damage": {
          "manual": true
        }
      },

      {
        "first": "svc",
        "last": "tre",
        "damage": {
          "auto": true
        }
      }, 

      {
        "first": "tre",
        "last": "hdf",
        "damage": {}
      }
    ]
  }
}

var myArr = myObj.Initial.claim;

console.log(myArr);

for (i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
  x += myArr[i].first + "<br>";

  if(myArr[i].damage.hasOwnProperty("auto")) {
    x += myArr[i].damage.auto + "<br>";
  }
}


document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks, Why is it giving as undefined in second line console.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `hasOwnProperty` function to check whether the damage is auto or not, check the below code snippet.

```js
'use strict';

var claims = {
  "Initial": {
    "claim": [{
      "first": "abc",
      "last": "xyz",
      "damage": {
        "auto": true,
        "manual": true
      }
    }, {
      "first": "mne",
      "last": "odc",
      "damage": {
        "manual": true
      }
    }, {
      "first": "svc",
      "last": "tre",
      "damage": {
        "auto": true
      }
    }, {
      "first": "tre",
      "last": "hdf",
      "damage": {}
    }]
  }
};

var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < claims.Initial.claim.length; i++) {
  if (claims.Initial.claim[i].damage.hasOwnProperty('auto')) {
    result.push(claims.Initial.claim[i]);
  }
}

console.log(result);

var x = '';
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  x += result[i].first + "<br>";
  x += result[i].damage.auto + "<br>";
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use **hasOwnProperty** to check if **auto** exists.

for example:

```
myObj.forEach(function(val) {
    if (val.damage.hasOwnProperty('auto') && val.damage.auto) {
        console.log(val.first, val.last);
    }
});
```